# Saving selected value on radiobutton in session

Tags: asp.net, session

we're building a quizsite where you should be able to answer questions, but also go back and see your selected value in the radiobuttonlist. We're encountering the problem that when you select a value, it does get saved into a sessionvariable, but when you select another value on the next question, this variable gets overwritten.

```
 protected void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //response redirect till samma sida - ta med query
        var i = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["questionNumber"];

        //while(i )
        i++;

        Session["questionNumber"] = i;

        //int j = int.Parse(rbListQuiz.SelectedValue);

        //ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        //arrayList.Add(j);

        //Session.Add("AnswerList",arrayList);

        Response.Redirect(string.Format("QuizContent.aspx?id={0}", _quizId));
```

Answer (score 0):

If session is not compalsary, then you can create cookie also. That will store all question & answers, question number as key, and answer as value for that key, and display according to key...